# Resizing a userControl on design view

Tags: c#, winforms, user-controls

I created a little UserControl and it works perfectly.

During design view in Visual Studio, I need to modify some things as the control is resized.

Here's the control:

[image]

It's a comboxBox, that is used to display the selected color; and a XAML usercontrol. But that's not quite important.

Basically what I want is that if someone resizes this control during design view in Visual Studio, that little black block remains 1px away from the right side of the control.

I have tried modifying the code in the InitializingComponent() method but it seems that you can't do that.

Thanks for the suggestions and help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should set the child control's `Anchor` to `Right`.
For more information, see [MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ty26a068.aspx).

Comment: Thank you that works exactly how I want it to. Is there someway to set up a control to always take up the width of the parent container, to fill it in so to speak?

Comment: @Sergio: Anchor it to both sides.  See the documentation.

Comment: Alternatively, `Dock` your controls `Fill` and `Right`.  See the documentation.